# Which access token should I be using?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

At our lab we are working on alternative metrics for research dissemination. As part of the project we are also collecting the Facebook engagement for a curated list of URLs. As we are looking at thousands of URLs the access token needs to be a long-lived one.

In order to access this information through the Graph API a regular user access token without any granted permissions is enough. Before the recent changes to the API we were using an App Access Token to run long-term crawlers.

Due to recent changes I am now facing the question which access token I should be using, as each seems not totally appropriate for the situation.

- User Access Token

  short lived; obviously not meant for this kind of task.
- App Access Token

  we don't actually need any users installing and accessing our App. Thus, setting up an app seems to be wrong too.
- Page Access Token

  Finally, we considered creating access tokens through an affiliated project's Facebook Page as our lab does not directly have FB page.

tl;dr: have long-running scripts that access the engagement endpoint of the Graph API (no permissions needed); which access token should I use?

Comment: What APIs are you calling. The API will tell you want access token you need

Comment: If you are talking about the URL node, any access token will do. The API rate limits are likely going to be your biggest problem, especially with an app that doesn’t have an actual user base.